# Oracle | XML Data Exported Out with Regex

Tags: oracle

I have created a query to pull data from XML column of table however I am having issue when XML has list of data i.e.

> Cola Brand has multiple code inside

See My query

```
select extract(cola_info, '/ns2:cola/coke/bottleCode', 'xmlns:ns2="http://myColaStaticInfo.com"') as op;
```

Output is something like

[image]

I would like to have highlighted content one after another and not together in one column.

Any idea!!!

MY XML look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:cola xmlns:ns2="http://myColaStaticInfo.com">
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2829</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2830</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2831</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
</ns2:cola>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLTable` is probably your best choice for this. Especially since `extract` has been deprecated.

```
with example_data as (select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:cola xmlns:ns2="http://myColaStaticInfo.com">
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2829</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2830</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
    <coke>
        <code>Bottle_2831</code>
        <label>Mirinda</label>
    </coke>
</ns2:cola>') as xml from dual)
-- query
select bottle_coke
from example_data e
cross join XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES('http://myColaStaticInfo.com' as "ns2"),
        '/ns2:cola/coke'
         PASSING e.xml
         COLUMNS 
           bottle_coke XMLTYPE PATH 'code'
         ) xt;
```

Output:

```
<code>Bottle_2829</code>
<code>Bottle_2830</code>
<code>Bottle_2831</code>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like working but taking very long to respond. We have 1318520 records. is there a way we can optimize it??